# How to get the value of DataGridView.SelectedRows().Cells() from different forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 forms and within each of the 2 forms there is a `DataGridView`(`chatform` and `prodetail`).

In the `chatform` I created a `DataGridView` which has a generated `Button` in each row.

Each `Button` when clicked will load a `prodetail` form and when in the `prodetail` form I want to get the value of the `SelectedRow.Cell` from the `DataGridView` in the originating `chatform`.

Code (`chatform`):

```
Public Sub loadtoDGV()
    Dim sqlq As String = "SELECT * FROM chattbl"
    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqladpt As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim tbl As New DataTable

    With sqlcmd
        .CommandText = sqlq
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With sqladpt
        .SelectCommand = sqlcmd
        .Fill(tbl)
    End With

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
        With DataGridView1
            .Rows.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("Username"), tbl.Rows(i)("Title"), tbl.Rows(i)("ChatDateTime"))
        End With
    Next
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ChatForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    loadtoDGV()
End Sub
```

Code (`DataGridView1.CellContentClick`):

```
Private Sub grdData_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim colName As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
    If colName = "Detail" Then
        Prodetail.Show()
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You clicked the button in row {0} of the Detail column", e.RowIndex))
    End If
End Sub
```

Code (`prodetail`):

```
Public Sub loadtoDGV2()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = ChatForm.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count
    MsgBox(i)

    Dim compareai As String = ChatForm.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(1).Value
    Dim sqlq As String = "SELECT * FROM Chattbl WHERE Title =" & compareai & ""
    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqladpt As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim tbl As New DataTable

    With sqlcmd
        .CommandText = sqlq
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With sqladpt
        .SelectCommand = sqlcmd
        .Fill(tbl)
    End With

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
        With DataGridView1
            .Rows.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("Username"), tbl.Rows(i)("Title"), tbl.Rows(i)("ChatDateTime"), tbl.Rows(i)("ChatContent"))
        End With
    Next
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Prodetail_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    loadtoDGV2()
End Sub
```

What have I done wrong?

I tried to use `MsgBox(i) i = SelectedRow(0)` assuming it would show the data for first row, but `DataGridView1` in `prodetail` does not load any data from the database.

I did not observe any errors, I just don't have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is you are calling the class instead of an instance. VB.NET will allow you to call an instance of the form as its name, but it will be the same instance across every use. I would not suggest doing this.

To start I would change this:

```
Private Sub grdData_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim colName As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
    If colName = "Detail" Then
        Prodetail.Show()
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You clicked the button in row {0} of the Detail column", e.RowIndex))
    End If
End Sub
```

To this:

```
Private Sub grdData_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim colName As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
    If colName = "Detail" Then
        Dim newDetailForm as new Proddetail(dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value)
        newDetailForm.show()
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You clicked the button in row {0} of the Detail column", e.RowIndex))
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in the `Proddetail` class you need to add a constructor and a member like this:

```
Private SearchValue as String 

Public Sub New(byval theSearchValue as string)
    InitalizeComponent()

    SearchValue = theSearchValue
End Sub
```

Then in your load routine:

```
Public Sub loadtoDGV2()      
    Dim sqlq As String = "SELECT * FROM Chattbl WHERE Title =" & SearchValue & ""
    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqladpt As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim tbl As New DataTable

    With sqlcmd
        .CommandText = sqlq
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With sqladpt
        .SelectCommand = sqlcmd
        .Fill(tbl)
    End With

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
        With DataGridView1
            .Rows.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("Username"), tbl.Rows(i)("Title"), tbl.Rows(i)("ChatDateTime"), tbl.Rows(i)("ChatContent"))
        End With
    Next
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

This should then display the details of the clicked row in a new instance of the `Proddetail` class.

I added a custom *paramaterized* constructor to the class that takes the value for the SQL query string. This way when you create a new instance of the form in your code, you can always pass in the search string that would lead to the details you want to view.

Comment: hi Pow-lan thx for the guides, is good i got the selectedrow but the datagridview1 in prodetail.form still load nothing, is it i have to call some argument into the constructor that you taught me~!

Comment: hi @Pow-lan the solution you posted not really work for me the datagridview inside prodetail.form still load nothing and no error observed, i really need help pls guide me~!

Comment: I would start by putting in some break points and see first if the query is returning the results, check if the `SearchValue` is what you expect it to be. Make sure that the `tbl` variable is being populated. etc. The constructor should be called first and then when you show the form, the `Load` will be called so unless there is something wrong with the SQL, you should be seeing something.